getting error for react-native-community_masked-view
Execution failed for task ':react-native-community_masked-view:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-community_masked-view:androidJdkImage'.
Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

Please resolve it , i tried a lot
